# Deleting Webhooks

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I have a shop with permission to read|write both orders and products. I setup some Webhooks and now I want to delete them. I am getting back 401 errors.

```
Starting with 4 webhooks
Trying to delete webhook 1982492
Error nil, Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
Trying to delete webhook 1982494
Error nil, Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
Trying to delete webhook 1982496
Error nil, Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
Trying to delete webhook 1982498
Error nil, Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.
Ended with 4 webhooks
```

So, how does one delete Webhooks set on products and orders?

Comment: Did you create these webhooks with the same app key that you're using to delete them?

Comment: Yes... it was a simple exercise. I realized I had no need for 3/4 created webhooks, so I tried to delete them. Used a rake task to create them, should've been able to use a rake task to kill them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a conversation with my Shopify console to show it working correctly:

```
$ shopify console
using iliketurtles.myshopify.com
irb(main):001:0> include ShopifyAPI
=> Object
irb(main):002:0> w = Webhook.create topic: "orders/create", address: "http://whatever.place.com", format: "json"
=> #<ShopifyAPI::Webhook:0x007f8ff1895778 @attributes={"topic"=>"orders/create", "address"=>"http://whatever.place.com", "format"=>"json", "id"=>2026848, "created_at"=>"2012-08-10T15:11:25-04:00", "updated_at"=>"2012-08-10T15:11:25-04:00"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true, @remote_errors=nil, @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveResource::Errors:0x007f8ff18948c8 @base=#<ShopifyAPI::Webhook:0x007f8ff1895778 ...>, @messages={}>>
irb(main):003:0> w.destroy
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

As others have mentioned, I think your issue is permissions related.

Comment: Interesting. Since rake task A created the Webhooks and rake task B failed to delete them, I guess the permissions that allowed task A to create them, were not sufficient to allow task B to delete them. I was able to create/delete using a test shop and the console though, so clearly, deleting Webhooks no longer puzzles me. Huzzah.

Answer (score 3):

Webhooks (and ScriptTags) that are created by an app are automatically removed when the app is uninstalled. It looks like that might be what is happening here.

If you are doing this in response to an app/uninstalled webhook, there is no reason. It's already handled!

Comment: Um. No. Has nothing to do with that, but it is true, I could just uninstall the App and yes, voila, no more Webhooks. Of course, that is silly.. but nonetheless.. viable when one is desperate.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the endpoint that the webhook connects to, it will be deleted after 19 attempts to connect to it.

From the shopify docs (http://wiki.shopify.com/WebHook#Automatic_Retries_and_Deletion)

> If an error is returned or a timeout occurs when sending a webhook,
>   Shopify will retry the same request for 48 hours using an exponential
>   back-off approach. In total 19 attempts will be made to deliver the
>   information.

You can also just delete the app, it will remove the webhooks

Comment: Again... that does not answer the question. If one creates a webhook, and then one wants to delete it, how is it deleted. Currently, any effort to delete a webhook produces an error. Uninstalling the App or removing the endpoint are brutish.